# Button class splitting lines

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having issues with my navigation buttons on my site. Working on my own Wordpress theme, and I am seeing buttons split lines on my site. You can see the issue here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJiit.png

If you want to visit the site, head to http://ehmbee.com and use U:demo P:demo to log in.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `white-space: nowrap;` to `.menubuttons` should fix your problem :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much for the fast reply! Just read up on the properties, and they are fantastic. Good stuff.

Comment: Yeah it's an absolute life saver some times ;) No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Comment: Oh and btw, @Dave, so that other users know your problem has been resolved click on the greyed out check mark below the voting system to the side of my answer. This will mark your question as answered. Also as a plus it gives me some reputation ;)